# mesh starter template cant find wallet

Tags: mesh

Ok so when running this live demo https://starter-template.meshjs.dev/
the "Connect wallet" button does not show any wallets. Even if I have installed Yoroi (and others) wallet extension in my chrome browser. What wallets are this demo supposed to find if not those in the browser extensions?? I may very well have misunderstood something fundamental as Im new to this.

Nils Christian